# libgdx - fixed timestep with interpolation - without box2d

Tags: libgdx, physics

I am having some problems implementing fixed timestep with graphic interpolation in my game.

Here is part of the render method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
    double newTime = TimeUtils.millis() / 1000.0;
    double frameTime = Math.min(newTime - currentTime, 0.25);

    accumulator += frameTime;
    currentTime = newTime;

    while (accumulator >= step)
    {
        updateObjects(step);
        accumulator -= step;
    }

    double alpha = accumulator / step;

    interpolateObjects((float)alpha);
}
```

Here is updateObjects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < world.level.gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
    GameObject go = world.level.gameObjects.get(i);
    go.prevPosition.set(go.position);//save previous position
    go.update(delta);
}
```

interpolateObjects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < world.level.gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
    GameObject go = world.level.gameObjects.get(i);
    go.position.lerp(go.prevPosition, alpha);
}
```

And then objects are rendered using position

As far as i can tell this should work, but it doesn't.
On high fps (200-400) everything is too slow, movement isn't even visible, i can just see that position is changing by 0.0001 or something like that

On low fps (10-20), movement is visible but again objects are very slow...

If i disable interpolation, than everything works as it should (on any fps), but then everything is jittery.

So the problem is somewhere in interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpolation `go.position.lerp(go.prevPosition, alpha)` is set up to assume that `prevPosition` was last updated at an exact multiple of `step`, but then when you update `prevPosition` like this `go.prevPosition.set(go.position)` you are destroying that contract on the first update of the frame. It also looks like you are lerping backwards (from position to the previous position).

I think you need a third vector so the last interpolated value is guaranteed not to influence your fixed time updates. Here I'll call it `interpPosition`, and it will be used for drawing instead of `position`.

You actually seem to technically be extrapolating (not interpolating) the value, since you are not updating ahead of time and your `alpha` is calculated from time left in the accumulator. If you want to linearly extrapolate from the last two positions calculated, you can do it like this (note the `1+alpha` to extrapolate):

```
for (int i = 0; i < world.level.gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
    GameObject go = world.level.gameObjects.get(i);
    interpPosition.set(go.prevPosition).lerp(go.position, 1 + alpha);
}
```

Depending on the speed of your simulation (and how fast objects can accelerate), this might still look jerky. I think a smoother, but computationally slower way to do this would be to do a fully calculated update using `alpha` instead of step time, and storing that in the `interpPosition` vector. But only do that if necessary.

Comment: works as expected on high fps (400), but it still looks jerky on <=60 fps.  
Can you explain this a bit more: `fully calculated update using alpha instead of step time`

Comment: Instead of interpolating/extrapolating the position linearly, you could do the same position calculation that you use in `update()` but apply it to `interpPosition` instead of `position` and use `alpha` as the delta time instead of `step`. Then acceleration and possibly collisions may be taken into account.